# Beta = 1 and 0. Type of portfolios

Tags: portfolio-management, capm, beta

I read in [E. Quian's "Quantitative Equitity Portoflio Management"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885580) the following:

> A traditional long-only portfolio [with unit beta] would have most of its risk in the market risk. However, a zero beta portfolio, typically a long-short market-neutral portfolio, would have no systematic risk.

Why are Beta=1 portfolios typically **long-only** and why are Beta=0 portfolios typically **long-short** and **market neutral**?

Answer (score 2):

Portfolio beta is a linear combination of each asset's beta times the weight of the asset in the portfolio.
Thus in general we have
$$
\beta = \sum_{i=1}^N w_i \beta_i
$$
where $w_i$ is the weight of asset $i$ and $\beta_i$ its beta.
If we assume that for stocks the betas are positive then
$\beta$ above is positive for positive weights.
If you have positive and negative weights then you can get $\beta=0$.

If you have a 130/30 portfolio - thus positive weights that sum to 130% and negative ones that sum to -30% then you can have a beta of approx 1.

Note that for mutual funds and individual investors it is not that easy to have short exposure to single stocks.

Comment: Thanks @Richard this is helpful, but I am having a hard time relating your answer to my question. Let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify it.

Comment: Is is because the more positive Beta is, the more long the portfolio is?

Comment: How do you measure beta? Ex-post it has something to with the performance of the assets that you hold, right? In a first approximation (which is also true ex-ante) the beta is what my formula above says. If you are long then you are long the market - an indication by how much is given by beta. What is your understanding of beta?

Comment: The beta of a typical stock is 1.0. What is the lowest beta stock that you know of? The lowest I know is Hawaii Electric (HE) with beta 0.4. I suppose with some effort I could find some a little lower than that. How are you going to combine together stocks with Beta of 0.4 or 0.3 into a portfolio with a beta of zero? You can't do it unless you short some stocks...

Comment: Yes, of course... This is what my answer says...